# Problema em converter numero (NumberFormat)

Tags: java

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade, pegando um valor através do meu form:

```
Double salario = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("salario"));
```

Sendo que o valor digitado pelo usuário vai ser algo do tipo: **2.687,35**. E esse valor, irei comparar com algumas outras variáveis `double` também.

Porém, `Double.parseDouble` esse método espera que o dado esteja no formato americano e sem separadores de milhar.

Então usei o `NumberFormat` da seguinte forma:

```
String salario = request.getParameter("salario");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt","BR")); 
Double s = nf.parse(salario).doubleValue();
```

Na linha:

```
Double s = nf.parse(salario).doubleValue();
```

Da o Seguinte erro:

```
unreported exception exception must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Já tentei colocar dentro do `try/catch` e continua com a mesma mensagem.

Comment: poderia mostrar seu código com o `try-catch`?

Comment: Fica assim: Double s; /// try {
            s = nf.parse(salario).doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `catch(ParseException)` é suficiente para tratar o erro e evitar a mensagem do compilador. Se o seu Java continuou a reportar a exceção citada pode ser por algum outro erro, por exemplo:

- Faltou salvar o arquivo para seu IDE recompilar a classe
- Faltou recompilar a classe por algum outro motivo
- Tem outro algum erro na classe impedindo a atualização do parser do seu IDE

Quanto ao seu código, fiz um teste com o NumberFormat do jeito que está na pergunta e ele não consegue fazer o parse do valor `2.687,35`, pois o formato de moeda exige o prefixo da respectiva moeda. Entretanto, se o valor for `R$ 2.689,35` ele consegue.

Veja um exemplo funcional:

```java
public class TestDouble {
    public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws ParseException {
        String salario = "R$ 2.689,35";
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR" ));
        System.out.println( nf.parse( salario ) );
    }
}
```

Se quiser fazer o parse sem o símbolo da moeda, basta usar o método `getInstance` ao invés do `getCurrencyInstance`. Exemplo:

```java
public class TestDouble {
    public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws ParseException {
        String salario = "2.689,35";
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR" ));
        System.out.println( nf.parse( salario ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: caso queira mostrar a documentação onde diz que o `ParseException` é o suficiente: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

```
String salario  = request.getParameter("salario").replace(".","").replace(",",".");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt","BR")); 
Double s = nf.parse(salario).doubleValue();
```

remove o "." que divide a casa decimal de milhar e troca a "," por "."